Should the review be skipped automatically if one wants to edit but the queue is full and the reviewer does not have full-edit privileges?
I know that there are already some similar questions here regarding the "problem", but I have not been able to find a discussion about this "solution":
The answer to this question suggests that it is wrong to close a review task with "No Action Needed" if it requires editing. Whilst I agree with this assessment, I still assume that many (especially new) users do this, e.g. because they interpreted the action as "there is nothing I can do" or they are frustrated with a lengthy canceled edit, or they simply think "the flaw is not that significant".
Wouldn't it be better for a task to be automatically skipped if an edit is not possible because the queue is too long (assuming the user does not have the appropriate permissions to do this without approval)? This could reduce frustration, especially for new reviewers, if they don't get the message after a potentially time-consuming edit that it can't be saved. It would also ensure that if a reviewer would have initially made an edit, the task would not be closed with "No Action Needed" afterwards and thus a possibly necessary edit would not be made.
So the suggestion would be to skip the task instead when submitting an edit action if the edit queue is already full. Alternatively or additionally, the reviewer could also be asked for a comment explaining the edit or its reason to the OP so that they can ask better questions in the future.

Sounds more like the usual unwillingness to hit the skip button when in doubt to be honest. Regardless, it is counterproductive to try and reduce frustration. It shouldn't exist to begin with. Frustration is a very important signal - that you need to stop reviewing. Immediately. Hiding that signal away behind measures which seem very fragile to me is only temporarily delaying a symptom.

@Gimby Reducing user frustration is a well-documented and accepted goal of UX design. It is wildly unreasonable to suggest that the solution to someone being frustrated on our platform is for them to just stop being frustrated. Frustration implies care; it implies the user had wants or expectations from the site that were not met. They could be unreasonable– to your point, which isn't something we can really solve (outside of helping convey reasonable expectations). But expecting reviewers not to become frustrated with crappy design, not to care when they review, is unhelpful, IMO.

@Gimby "Regardless, it is counterproductive to try and reduce frustration. It shouldn't exist to begin with." At first I thought you meant that the queue shouldnt' exist to begin with. I'd actually support that. It's a terrible design that only makes sense given false premises about how the site works. Since review work is voluntary anyway, people who want to review should be given better tools to search and filter for the things they're best qualified to review. If the goal is to herd cats into 100% review coverage, that probably became impossible in 2009.

I'm not sure an auto-skip is the best option. Bumping users to the next item without any sort of warning after they click "Edit" sounds like it would be pretty confusing and unexpected!
Some sort of dialogue pop-up though, which told users the situation, could definitely be an improvement, I think. The dialogue could even include a built-in "Skip" button, with guidance that indicates "No action needed" is decidedly incorrect if the post really needs an edit.

No matter which way you slice it, the current status quo of allowing users to start an edit but blocking it upon submission if the queue is full is a downright terrible experience (and doesn't do us any favors in terms of keeping reviewers around). There are plenty of complaints filed in this department.
Another path probably worth considering is to allow all suggested edits from the review queue to always go through (into the suggested edits queue). We already allow edits started before the queue is full to always be submitted; maybe the real solution here is to give reviewers unilateral ability to submit those suggestions, because they're taking the time to review at all?
